# Polymer accessing model data on-click

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to add an on-click inside a Polymer dom-repeat section. Looking at the documentation [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates), Polymer seems to do this automatically and store the data in a 'model' property.

Using this, I've been able to get the data (username) I want by doing this:

```
let username = event.model.__data__.user.username;
```

However, although this works, it definitely doesn't look right... Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Its recommended to use `on-tap` rather than `on-click` as it is more mobile device friendly. You can check that  [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners) in the documentation

Comment: Good spot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, despite what is printed out if you do console.log(event.model), you can actually just bypass the **data** altogether and just do:

```
event.model.user.username;
```